# PHP Get Object from Cache

Tags: php, caching

I'am using memcache to store PHP class object using serialize and unserialize.
Is any way to get back original class object using new Method?

My example:

```
class Test
{
    public $id;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        if (InCache($id)) {
            return unserialize(GetFromCache($id));
        } else {
            $this->id = $id;
            SaveToCache(serialize($this));
        }
    }
}
```

Calling:

```
$t = new Test(1);
```

If ID is in cache or NOT, I need back same output:

```
Test Object
(
  [id] => 1
)
```

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in php you can't `return` in a `__construct` function

you could get the new Object from a Factory Funktion like this:

```
class Test
{
    public $id;

    protected function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        SaveToCache(serialize($this));
    }

    public static function getNewObject($id)
    {
        if (InCache($id)) {
            return unserialize(GetFromCache($id));
        } else {
            return new self($id);
        }
    }
}
```

Calling:

```
$t = Test::getNewObject(1);
```

Comment: Thanks. Last question: There is no selfreplace function to do same solution?

Comment: @Ondra There is no selfreplace function in php. That is correct.